# Question about sparse graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

We call a graph $G=(V,E)$ $k$-sparse if there is a partition $E = \bigcup_{i = 1}^k E_i$ of the edges into $k$ disjoint parts such that each graph $(V,E_i)$ is a forest.

I am trying to prove that $k \geq |E|/(|V|-1)$ holds for any $k$-sparse graph.

I tried to write an algorithm that remove edges from $G$ until $G$ became acyclic and the for all edges that we removed assigns them to a new piece $E_j$.
But I donˋt know how to prove that my algorithm return me a $k$ that help us to resolve the question.

Comment: Hello. I find 2 obscure. What do you mean by "empty group"? Is it a graph with no edge? Isn't 2 implied by 1? Do you mean $k\ge |E|/(|V|-1)$? Does "un-circle" mean "with no cycle"?

Comment: I've (hopefully) fixed the notation. But now that I can read the question, it looks rather trivial to me. How did you arrive at it? Why is this research-level?

Comment: $|E|=\sum_{i=1}^k|E_i|\le k(|V|-1)$. Looks like a homework exercise.